# Unbound classpath variable

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When rebuilding my project with Maven I sometimes get hundreds of

> 'unbound classpath variable M2_REPO/etc/..'

in my eclipse errors, most of the time when I rebuild again it goes away but on this occasion its cursed me enough to stick around.

When actually going through the file system, the jars it details that are not there are actually there. Eclipse is just not seeing them for some reason. My m2_repo is correctly referenced in my preferences->java->classpathvariables section and my environmental variables are likewise properly set.

Any ideas for me folks?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you already did several times **STEP 1**, go to **STEP 2**

**STEP 1**
Try deleting and redefining env vars:

- Open the Eclipse Preferences [Window - Preferences]
- Go to [Java - Build Path - Classpath Variables]
- Click New and set its name as M2_REPO
- Click Folder and select your Maven repository folder. For example, my repository folder is `C:/Users/user/.m2/repository`
- Rebuild the Project.

Beside from inside of Eclipse, *you can also add the **M2_REPO variable*** from command line using this Maven command:

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace=<path-to-eclipse-workspace> eclipse:add-maven-repo
```

**STEP 2**
If your build path is correctly defined, check Maven settings.xml:

```
Window --> Preferences --> Maven ---> User Settings
```

If not, set it there and change localRepository path in settings tag inside settings.xml. Normally you will find settings.xml in .m2 folder under the user folder (for eg. C:\Documents and Settings\userName.m2).

Comment: Hi Jordi, These are all great ideas and thanks for the reply but tried and tested im afraid. the strange bit is that it happens but sorts itself out with another build. I am preplexed

Comment: I had the same problem in Eclipse (Mars version in my case). And I tried Jordy's solution, no luck. Then I just restarted Eclipse, and the problem's gone.

Comment: JordiCastilla: May be you need to add the STEP 3: Restart eclipse. First of all this issue just came up after restart of system i.e. had no issue earlier. and I performed step1 (step 2 was already set) and then restart it after reading comments from @Yuci. FYI

Answer (score 10):

Well, I tried the steps in @Jordi's answer. But those didn't make any difference. And I tried some ritualistic things in eclipse such as:

- closing the project and opening it
- restarting the IDE
- cleaning and rebuilding etc...

with no success.

Then strange thing happened when I changed the Java complience level to **1.8** and revert it back to **1.6**. It worked! All unbound classpath variable errors are gone now.

Comment: While the accepted answer did not work for me changing from 1.8 to 1.6 and back to 1.8 worked for me too. Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 1):

## `Update Project` worked for me :

### Step 1 : Select Project Folder

Select the project folder that is giving the error.

### Step 2 : Update Maven Project

`Alt + F5` shortcut **OR** `right-click >> Maven >> Update Project`.

### Step 3 : Finalize

`Click OK` and let it *update*.

**The errors should disappear after that.**

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before more than once and I don't use the maven plugin so I dont have windows -> Preferences->Maven. 
To resolve this  `'unbound classpath variable M2_REPO/etc/..`' though you have M2_REPO variable setup issue ->  Rename  M2_REPO variable to something else (M2_REPO2 for eg)  and then correct it back to M2_REPO and this issue goes away.

Comment: M2_REPO Variable is  unmodifiable.

Comment: Jagadeesh, I have it as a classpath variable  in eclipse . If you go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variable select M2_REPO and click on edit you should be able to change it. Im not sure what you mean by unmodifable.

Answer (score 0):

Mars.2 was having this problem for me. Tried all these suggestions, then deleted the ~/.m2/repository/.metadata folder, restarted eclipse, and M2_REPO was there.

Got there by looking at Maven - User Settings, but there's no settings.xml, but there was a .metadata folder, which if you drill down there's a jdt file with the eclipse .m2 repository location. Figured it wasn't doing any good, so I deleted it. After restarting eclipse and M2_REPO is configured, the ~/.m2/repository/.metadata folder is still deleted. Must have conflicted with something else in the workspace. Don't know how it got there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting the M2_REPO variable several times, but finally the only thing helped was starting Eclipse with **-clean** parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Error was gone after uninstall of the Maven Integration from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the things above but none of them works for me. Here is the solution which works for me;

**right click to project>>Build Path> Configure Build Path>Libraries**

You are gonna see all jars that you see in problems (M2_REPO....)

**>>>Select these jars>>> Remove>>Apply and Close**

exclamation mark disappears and all errors gone

Note: before that I also did mvn clean install, update project when did not help I tried this

Hope helps for you...

Answer (score 0):

`M2_REPO` should point to `~/.m2/repository` (in Eclpise `Windows > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables > New...`)

maven command is:
`mvn -Declipse.workspace="path-to-eclipse-workspace" eclipse:configure-workspace` (**NOT** `eclipse:add-maven-repo` as sugested in the first answer)